# How can I verify my code?

Tags: matlab, dsp-core

````
Fs = 16000;Channels = 1; bits = 16;
r= audioread('myWAVaudiofile.wav');
duration = 3;
sound (r,Fs,bits);
t = 0:1/Fs:(length(r)-1)/Fs;
subplot (2,1,1); plot (t,r,'LineWidth',1.5);
xlabel('time (sec)'); ylabel('Amplitude');
title('Time Domain plot of the Signal');
n = length (r); F = 0 :(n-1)*Fs/n;
Y = fft(r,n);
F_0 = (-n/2:n/2-1).*(Fs/n);
Y_0 = fftshift(Y);
AY_0 = abs(Y_0);
subplot(2,1,2); plot(F_0,AY_0,'LineWidth',1.5);
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)'); ylabel('Amplitude');
title('Frequency Domain Plot Of Audio Signal');```
````

How can I:

- Verify that that 12000 sample is indeed occurring at 0.75 sec spot.
- Verify the spectral spacing.
- What is the frequency (in Hz) at k = 8000 and k = 3000.

Comment: Hi John- Welcome to DSP.SE! Can you explain this with words expanding on what you are doing and the application and include the relevant plots? This will help avoid someone needing to run your code to answer your question. Note we don't typically debug code at this site (see https://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), but you may have a good signal processing question in here. Thanks!

Comment: How can i verify that the 12000th sample occurs at 0.75seconds?

Comment: @John- This isn't really helpful. Help us to help you! Please write out your complete problem so that someone doesn't even need to read your code to understand what you are trying to do.  Add a plot if you can, that would really help communicate your issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Verify that that 12000 sample is indeed occurring at 0.75 sec spot.

`t(12000)`

> Verify the spectral spacing.

`F_0(2) - F_0(1)`

> What is the frequency (in Hz) at k = 8000 and k = 3000.

`F_0(8000), F_0(3000)`